# Getting a single table row from a multi row array

Tags: php, sql

I have a mysqli table with four columns, it has for the purpose of this question three selected rows.

I am SELECTING * from the table and assembling all three rows into a single array with:

// Raw array
echo json_encode($poll_answers);

What I now wish to do is to grab and display two values [title] and [votes] from each of the 3 single lines individually, and display them with a % bar.

It works ok with a foreach command looping through and displaying:

```
<?=template_header('Poll Results')?>
<div class="content poll-result">
<h2><?=$poll['title']?></h2>
<p><?=$poll['desc']?></p>
<div class="wrapper">
    
    <?php foreach ($poll_answers as $poll_answer): ?>
    <div class="poll-question"><p><?=$poll_answer['title']?> <span>(<? 
    =$poll_answer['votes']?> Votes)</span></p>
    <div class="result-bar" style="width:<? 
    =@(($poll_answer['votes']/$total_votes)*100)?>%"><? 
     =@round(($poll_answer['votes']/$total_votes)*100)?>%</div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

If I use [0] , [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfkUa.png) or [2] in the above to try to select a row it doesn't run.

I suspect there is something simple I'm missing, and I'd be grateful for some help.

[The image shows three rows output using 'foreach' - but I need just one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfkUa.png)

Comment: with non-keyed array `$poll_answers[0]` should work, but jst in case you can find wich keys are been used `var_dump($poll_answers)`, or too just get the keys `var_dump(array_keys($poll_answers))`

Answer (score -1):

Once you fetched data(rows) from the database, you need to convert it to an associative array using fetch_assoc() to print data like this. Check this example in [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).